# File upload after rename the file in zend

Tags: file-upload, zend-form, file-rename

This is my form

```
class Admin_Form_RoomtypeForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {

       $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
       $name->setLabel('Name :');

       $imagePath = '/home/dinuka/image';

       $image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image');
       $image->setLabel('Image URL :');
       $image->setDestination($imagePath);
       $image->addValidators(array(array('IsImage', false)));

       $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');

       $this->addElements(array($name, $image, $submit));
   }
}
```

This is my controller

```
class Admin_RoomtypesController extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{
    public function addAction()
    {
         $form = new Admin_Form_RoomtypeForm();

         if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
              $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
              $form->populate($formData);       

              $name = $form->getValue('name');

         }
    }
}
```

Now i want to upload file after change file name as $name value. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I done it as following.

-Form -

```
class Admin_Form_RoomtypeForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {

       $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
       $name->setLabel('Name :');

       $image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image');
       $image->setLabel('Image URL :');           
       $image->addValidators(array(array('IsImage', false)));

       $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');

       $this->addElements(array($name, $image, $submit));
   }
}
```

-Controller -

```
class Admin_RoomtypesController extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{
    public function addAction()
    {
         $form = new Admin_Form_RoomtypeForm();

         if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
              $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
              $form->populate($formData);       

              $name = $form->getValue('name');
              $image = $form->getValue('image');

              $temp = explode(".", $image);
              $ext = $temp[count($temp)-1];

              $imageName = $name .'.'. $ext;

              $fullPath  = $imagePath ."/". $imageName; 
              copy("/tmp/". $image, $fullPath);    
         }
    }
}
```

default image is upload to /tmp folder. We can change it using `setDestination()` method as my example.

Thank for All

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this for one of my projects, except i needed unique filenames. This isn't a perfect solution, but it may put you on the right track:

```
<?php
class My_Filter_UniqueFilename implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
  public function filter($value)
  {
    $upload_dir = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
    $ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = $upload_dir . "/" . md5(microtime()) . "." . $ext;
    $result = rename($value, $filename);

    if($result === true) {
    return $upload_dir . $filename;
    }

    require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
    throw new Zend_Filter_Exception(sprintf("File '%s' could not be renamed. An error occured while processing the file.", $value));
  }
}
```