# Unable to rename the uploaded image in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have the controller code as follows:

```
    $form_company=new Project_Form_AddCompany();
    $this->view->form=$form_company;

    $form_company->setAction('add-Company');
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($form_company->isValid($formData)) {

             $company_name = $this->_getParam('company', 0);
             echo $company_name;
            // success - do something with the uploaded file
            $uploadedData = $form_company->getValues();
           $form_company->uploaded_file->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array('target' => $company_name.'.jpg')));
            Zend_Debug::dump($uploadedData, '$uploadedData');
            //echo 'End: ';


        }

    // action body
}
```

While in form I have following code:

```
<?php

class Project_Form_AddCompany extends Zend_Form
{

public function init()
{
    $company=new Zend_Form_Element_Text('company');
    $company->setLabel('CompanyName')
            ->setRequired(true);

    $com_des=new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('com_des');
    $com_des->setLabel('CompanyDescription')
             ->setAttrib('cols', '40')
             ->setAttrib('rows', '4')
             ->setAttrib('style', 'resize: none;')
             ->setRequired(true)
              ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

    $com_addr=new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('com_addr');
    $com_addr->setLabel('CompanyAddress')
             ->setAttrib('cols', '40')
             ->setAttrib('rows', '4')
             ->setAttrib('style', 'resize: none;')
             ->setRequired(true)
              ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

    $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('uploaded_file');

    $file->setDestination(PUBLIC_PATH . '/images/')
          ->setLabel('File')
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->addValidator('NotEmpty');


    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');

    $this->addElements(array($company,$com_des,$com_addr,$file,$submit));

}

}
```

Since I have to rename the uploaded image to $company_name.png thats why I am using addFilter method in controller where $company_name is the value of textfield company(in form) input by user.But name has not been changed.To rename What should be done??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the filter after the form values have been retrieved, this is why it's not being applied.

Wouldn't it be simpler just to call the [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) PHP function after you have retrieved the uploaded file?

Something like the following:

```
if (!$form_company->uploaded_file->receive()) {
    // Error!
}

$location = $form_company->uploaded_file->getFileName();

move_uploaded_file($location, $yourLocation . $company_name.'.jpg';
```

If not, it's always possible to use `rename()` to rename the uploaded file to whatever name you need.

Hope that helps,

Comment: In my case $location and $yourLocation are same since I have specified path already in form but here after writing above code image was not renamed.

Comment: that means move_uploaded_file is returning false: here $location is  "C:\Users\398853\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MST\public/images\Chrysanthemum.jpg" while $yourLocation.$company_name.'.jpg' is "C:\Users\398853\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MST\public/images/jhm.jpg               "

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited my answer for the posterity. You can mark it as "accepted" if finally it helped solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I did it following way.

[File upload after rename the file in zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435569/file-upload-after-rename-the-file-in-zend/8532785#8532785)

I think this question is helpful for u.